# Skipping unreadable files from damaged USB harddisk (Windows)

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-transfer, usb-storage, hard-drive-failure

I have a USB connected harddisk of which many (1000s) files can not be read. The problem is, these files seem randomly distributed over the drive, and it takes a very long time (over an hour) before the drive gives up on trying to read each of these files. So a simple copy process is out of the question.

I have in my mind two possible ways to approach this. I'm not sure how I would perform this in practice, if it is at all possible.

My first thought would be to minimize the amount of time it takes before giving up trying to copy a file, to for example 10 seconds. However I have not found any way to do this, maybe this would require an OS- or hardware-level change? I have tried killing copy processes, but short of unplugging the drive nothing seems to work. (And before anybody suggests: no, "robocopy /w:10" does not fix this.)

My second thought would be to log every file that is being tried, then when a file copy gets stuck I can unplug the drive, and restart the process, skipping the problematic file by skipping any files that have previously been logged. Since we're talking 1000s of files, I have to be able to run multiple processes parallel.

Is there anybody able to help me with my problem? Tell me how I can perform either option, or suggest other approaches?

Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

You tried `robocopy /w:10`, but I guess what you need here is to use `robocopy /r:1` (or a slightly larger number, in case you observe that this helps to save more files).

[Robocopy documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) says, default number of retries for the same file is one million, `/r:1` reduces this to one. Note also `/w` does not change the time until robocopy gives up, it controls the time between two retries.

Comment: Limiting the number of retries for robocopy doesn't change that it takes over an hour before a read timeout. With 1000s of unreadable files, this will still take 1000s of hours to read all the files, even when limiting to only 1 retry. This is simply not realistic. 

I need a method to either decrease the timeout value, or one 
that allows me to unplug the drive and continue with the next file after plugging in again.

Comment: @Peter: I did not try this, but maybe a sector-copying tool has a better time-out mechanism? Like [HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool](https://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/) or [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/)? Or the Unix tool "dd", which is also available for Windows? Note it you manage to make an image, you still have to extract the files. see [this question from the Clonezilla FAQ](https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq#43_read_ntfsimg_content.faq).